# Quickly assign multiple values to `this` in class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a class in which I have to assign multiple variables to this. Is there a nicer way (with less code) to tackle something like this:

```
class Foo {
  constructor(firstName, lastName, age) {
    const fullName = firstName + lastName;
    const age = age * 5;

    this.fullName = fullName;
    this.age = age;
  }
}
```

I know I could replace `const fullName` with `this.fullName`, but that's getting very messy when having to do larger pieces of logic (see full case below)

I've tried using `Object.assign({}, this, {fullName, age})` but without much luck.

Full case:

```
class AudioPlayer {
  static init() {
    const audio = new Audio();
    audio.loop = true;
    audio.autoplay = true;

    const audioFiles = {
      slow: 'mp3/slow.mp3',
      medium: 'mp3/medium.mp3',
      fast: 'mp3/fast.mp3'
    };

    audio.src = audioFiles.medium;

    const audioContext = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();

    const audioAnalyser =  audioContext.createAnalyser();
    audioAnalyser.fftSize = 1024;

    const audioSource =  audioContext.createMediaElementSource(audio);
    audioSource.connect(audioAnalyser);
    audioAnalyser.connect( audioContext.destination);

    const bufferLength = audioAnalyser.frequencyBinCount;

    this.audio = audio;
    this.audioFiles = audioFiles;
    this.audioContext = audioContext;
    this.audioAnalyser = audioAnalyser;
    this.audioSource = audioSource;
    this.bufferLength = bufferLength;
  }
}
```

✌

Comment: `static init`? What's that? You should not use `class` syntax if you don't have a `constructor`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Object.assign()` should work. Just skip the first argument, so that all other values would be merged into `this`.

```
Object.assign(this, {fullName, age})
```

Comment: Of course! The data was being merged into an empty object which was returned. Thanks!